# Can't get sender email address with EWS Java API

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using EWS Java API 1.1.5. I am trying to get the email sender as follows:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(
    WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
    for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
        if (item instanceof EmailMessage) {
            String senderEmail = ((EmailMessage) item).getSender().getAddress();
            System.out.println("Sender Email: " + senderEmail);
        }
    }
);
```

But it always returns `null`. I also tried the following:

```
String senderEmail = ((EmailMessage) item).getFrom().getAddress();
```

But it also returns `null`. I can see that the email contains sender like:

```
Test User <testuser@testdomain.com>
```

It appears in the message and also when replying to the email.

Please advise how to fix this issue.

Comment: Using the .NET API, if you do not call Load (as per the Answer), the From and Sender for an internal e-mail are exchange addresses (RoutingType = "EX"). But if you call Load then they are SMTP addresses - yay.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

found the solution, i have to use `item.load();` before getting the sender email address.

Answer (score 0):

While the above works perfectly, as an alternative, loading is not necessary if the search is done with the view of the properties, consider the code snippet

```
    ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
    view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
    view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, 
                                        ItemSchema.Subject,
                                        ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, 
                                        EmailMessageSchema.From));
    
    SearchFilterCollection searchCollection=new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection();
    searchCollection.add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, !unreadEmailOnly));
    
    FindItemsResults<Item> result=exchangeService.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, 
                                                            searchCollection, 
                                                            view);
```

Subsequently, EmailMessage.getFrom().getAddress() can be called.